# Why does Ruby open-uri's open return a StringIO in my unit test, but a FileIO in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, imagemagick, open-uri

I inherited a Rails 2.2.2 app that stores user-uploaded images on Amazon S3. The attachment_fu-based `Photo` model offers a `rotate` method that uses `open-uri` to retrieve the image from S3 and MiniMagick to perform the rotation.

The `rotate` method contains this line to retrieve the image for use with MiniMagick:

```
temp_image = MiniMagick::Image.from_file(open(self.public_filename).path)
```

`self.public_filename` returns something like

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/photos/98/photo.jpg
```

Retrieving the image and rotating it work just fine in the running application in production and development. However, the unit test fails with

```
TypeError: can't convert nil into String
    /Users/santry/Development/totspot/vendor/gems/mini_magick-1.2.3/lib/mini_magick.rb:34:in `initialize'
    /Users/santry/Development/totspot/vendor/gems/mini_magick-1.2.3/lib/mini_magick.rb:34:in `open'
    /Users/santry/Development/totspot/vendor/gems/mini_magick-1.2.3/lib/mini_magick.rb:34:in `from_file'
```

The reason is that when the model method is called in the context of the unit test, `open(self.public_filename)` is returning a `StringIO` object that contains the image data. The `path` method on this object returns `nil` and `MiniMagick::Image.from_file` blows up.

When this very same model method is called from the `PhotosController`, `open(self.public_filename)` returns a `FileIO` instance tied to a file named, eg, `/tmp/open-uri7378-0` and the file contains the image data.

Thinking the cause must be some environmental difference between test and development, I fired up the console under the development environment. But just as in the unit test, `open('http://...')` returned a `StringIO`, *not* a `FileIO`.

I've traced my way through open-uri and all the relevant application-specific code and can find no reason for the difference.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The code responsible for this is in the Buffer class in open-uri. It starts by creating a StringIO object and only creates an actual temp file in the local filesystem when the data exceeds a certain size (10 KB).

I assume that whatever data your test is loading is small enough to be held in a StringIO and the images you are using in the actual application are large enough to warrant a TempFile. The solution is to use methods which are common to both classes, in particular the read method, with MiniMagick::Image#from_blob:

```
temp_image = MiniMagick::Image.from_blob(open(self.public_filename, &:read))
```

Comment: Don't do `open(self.public_filename).read`, you don't know when the handle will be closed. Use `open(self.public_filename, &:read)` instead, which uses block-form and explicitly closes when done. And it's not really more code.

Comment: FYI, `from_blob` is now deprecated in favor of `read`. See https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick/blob/f309fbf390cd21a845264bca9bec95b9bdae8029/lib/mini_magick.rb#L82

Answer (score 80):

The open-uri library uses a constant to set the 10KB size limit for StringIO objects.

```
> OpenURI::Buffer::StringMax
=> 10240
```

You can change this setting to 0 to prevent open-uri from ever creating a StringIO object. Instead, this will force it to always generate a temp file.

Just throw this in an initializer:

```
# Don't allow downloaded files to be created as StringIO. Force a tempfile to be created.
require 'open-uri'
OpenURI::Buffer.send :remove_const, 'StringMax' if OpenURI::Buffer.const_defined?('StringMax')
OpenURI::Buffer.const_set 'StringMax', 0
```

You can't just set the constant directly. You need to actually remove the constant and then set it again (as above), otherwise you'll get a warning:

```
warning: already initialized constant StringMax
```

**UPDATED 12/18/2012**: Rails 3 doesn't require OpenURI by default, so you need to add `require 'open-uri'` at the top of the initializer. I updated the code above to reflect that change.

Comment: Micah, This looks great but I'm getting errors when I try it in a Rails 3 app. It looks like a Buffer object hasn't been created yet.

uninitialized constant OpenURI (NameError)

Comment: Thanks, Paul, I updated the code in the answer. Thanks, Michael, I love you too.

Comment: Changing this application-wide, in the initializer, what performance implications does it have?

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  Came here from CSV error `no implicit conversion of StringIO into String`

Comment: This has been driving me nuts for a couple weeks now.  Thanks for this answer!

Comment: padame loves you bro

Comment: Amazing answer that has stood the test of time. Firm handshakes, Micah.

Comment: Yeah the 10kb threshold caused a production bug in our app; forcing `OpenURI` to always create a temp file definitely did the trick. If the file being read was < 10kb it would create a `StringIO` object which was not handled by our backend nicely. HUGE props for your answer here, lifesaver. Also, who the f decided to implement this threshold and change the returned object type? Very subtle bug-inducing threshold... the `open` method really shouldn't change behavior based on the file size being read... but that's just my 2¢ tho!

Answer (score 0):

Now `OpenURI::Buffer::StringMax` can be set directly:

```
require 'open-uri'
OpenURI::Buffer::StringMax = 0
```

but with a warning:

```
warning: already initialized constant OpenURI::Buffer::StringMax
```