# Storing image using open URI and paperclip having size less than 10kb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, stringio

I want to import some icons from my old site. The size of those icons is less than 10kb. So when  I am trying to import the icons its returning stringio.txt file.

```
require "open-uri"
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_attached_file :icon,  :path => ":rails_root/public/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
  def icon_from_url(url)
    self.icon = open(url)
   end    
end
```

In rake task.

```
   category = Category.new
   category.icon_from_url "https://xyz.com/images/dog.png"
   category.save
```

Comment: You're trying to retrieve images from another site, having some sort of problem, yes? Why the paperclip stuff then? Why don't you just download the icons and upload them separately? You do realize that paperclip if for handling file uploads, right?

Comment: i want to add the icons in paperclip style. There are some 400 icons..its not possible for me to create tons of folders.

Comment: @coreyward  more over these icons are related to some category and each category has lots of other details.

Comment: What is the problem/error/question ?

Comment: @Michaël-Witrant The size of those icons is less than 10kb. So when I am trying to import the icons its returning stringio.txt file.

Comment: So you want to change the name of the files paperclip saves?

Comment: no. I want to save those files. I can downlaod 300 icons and place it in directories like paperclip does. But when i am trying to fecth those files its returning stringio.txt files as their sizes are less than 10kb.

Comment: What does the file contain? I tried that on a Paperclip attachment: the filename is stringio.txt but it contains the image.

Comment: @Mohit Kevin's solution below worked for me!

Comment: @oreoshake  Lemme check again then..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try:

```
def icon_from_url(url)
  extname = File.extname(url)
  basename = File.basename(url, extname)

  file = Tempfile.new([basename, extname])
  file.binmode

  open(URI.parse(url)) do |data|  
    file.write data.read
  end

  file.rewind

  self.icon = file
end
```

Comment: this code worked for the first image but then nothing. I have a loop of some 350 images. I double checked the links. its perfectly fine. In addition image name is not the same.

Comment: @Mohit Are you calling `save` on your model after performing this method?

Comment: Setting `original_filename` on the IO returned by open-uri is much simpler and faster.

Comment: @MichaëlWitrant I found that PaperClip 3.5.1 performs MIME type validations based on the Tempfile's filename. It doesn't matter if `original_filename` is set. I used @KevinSylvestre's method to force the Tempfile to have the correct extension, and thus PaperClip "guessed" the correct MIME type. (You could argue that the validation is useless in this scenario, but having the correct MIME type stored in the DB might be useful.)

Answer (score 9):

To override the default filename of a "fake file upload" in Paperclip (`stringio.txt` on small files or an almost random temporary name on larger files) you have 2 main possibilities:

Define an `original_filename` on the IO:

```
def icon_from_url(url)
  io = open(url)
  io.original_filename = "foo.png"
  self.icon = io
end
```

You can also get the filename from the URI:

```
io.original_filename = File.basename(URI.parse(url).path)
```

Or replace `:basename` in your `:path`:

```
has_attached_file :icon, :path => ":rails_root/public/:attachment/:id/:style/foo.png", :url => "/:attachment/:id/:style/foo.png"
```

Remember to alway change the `:url` when you change the `:path`, otherwise the `icon.url` method will be wrong.

You can also define you own [custom interpolations](http://www.viget.com/extend/paperclip-custom-interpolation/) (e.g. `:rails_root/public/:whatever`).

Comment: I am trying to use this but if I try to set original_filename on io in this example I am getting an

NoMethodError: undefined method `original_filename='

Error on the tempfile. Ruby 1.8.7 rails 2.3.8

Comment: @DustinM. This works: `def io.original_filename; "foo.png"; end`

Comment: I can confirm that this works.  In order to access a local variable, I had to use define_method:

    open(doc.url) do |file|
      file.singleton_class.instance_eval do
        define_method(:original_filename) { doc.title }
      end
    end

Comment: This doesn't work due to the undefined method error.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there I think, try opening parsed uri, not the string.

```
require "open-uri"
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_attached_file :icon,  :path =>:rails_root/public/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
  def icon_from_url(url)
    self.icon = open(URI.parse(url))
  end    
end
```

Of course this doesn't handle errors

Comment: Its not going to save extenstion!

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable OpenURI from ever creating a StringIO object, and force it to create a temp file instead. See this SO answer:

[Why does Ruby open-uri's open return a StringIO in my unit test, but a FileIO in my controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694115/why-does-ruby-open-uris-open-return-a-stringio-in-my-unit-test-but-a-fileio-in/6632032#6632032)

Answer (score -2):

In the past, I found the most reliable way to retrieve remote files was by using the command line tool "wget". The following code is mostly copied straight from an existing production (Rails 2.x) app with a few tweaks to fit with your code examples:

```
class CategoryIconImporter
  def self.download_to_tempfile (url)
    system(wget_download_command_for(url))
    @@tempfile.path
  end

  def self.clear_tempfile
    @@tempfile.delete if @@tempfile && @@tempfile.path && File.exist?(@@tempfile.path)
    @@tempfile = nil
  end

  def self.set_wget
    # used for retrieval in NrlImage (and in future from other sies?)
    if !@@wget
      stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3('which wget')
      @@wget = stdout.gets
      @@wget ||= '/usr/local/bin/wget'
      @@wget.strip!
    end
  end
  def self.wget_download_command_for (url)
    set_wget
    @@tempfile = Tempfile.new url.sub(/\?.+$/, '').split(/[\/\\]/).last
    command = [ @@wget ]
    command << '-q'
    if url =~ /^https/
      command << '--secure-protocol=auto'
      command << '--no-check-certificate'
    end
    command << '-O'
    command << @@tempfile.path
    command << url
    command.join(' ')
  end

  def self.import_from_url (category_params, url)
    clear_tempfile

    filename = url.sub(/\?.+$/, '').split(/[\/\\]/).last
    found = MIME::Types.type_for(filename)
    content_type = !found.empty? ? found.first.content_type : nil

    download_to_tempfile url

    nicer_path = RAILS_ROOT + '/tmp/' + filename
    File.copy @@tempfile.path, nicer_path

    Category.create(category_params.merge({:icon => ActionController::TestUploadedFile.new(nicer_path, content_type, true)}))
  end
end
```

The rake task logic might look like:

```
[
  ['Cat', 'cat'],
  ['Dog', 'dog'],
].each do |name, icon|
  CategoryIconImporter.import_from_url {:name => name}, "https://xyz.com/images/#{icon}.png"
end
```

This uses the mime-types gem for content type discovery:

```
gem 'mime-types', :require => 'mime/types'
```