# paperclip renaming stringio.txt using instance_write

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, omniauth

I am using omniauth-facebook and trying to get the profile picture to show up using paperclip.  Here is the code I use to get the picture to my User model

```
def picture_from_url(url)
    self.profile_pic =open(url)
end
```

However, it always saves as stringio.txt. So searching on this behavior I found out that paperclip allows for callbacks so I wrote the following method in the User model to rename the filename

```
def rename_profile_pic
    self.profile_pic.instance_write :filename, "#{self.username}.jpg"
end
```

and passed it to the callback

```
before_post_process :rename_profile_pic
```

But this doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas how i can fix this ?

thanks

Answer (score 10):

In case you haven't found the solution yet:

```
data = StringIO.new(file_data)
data.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }

data.content_type = content_type
data.original_filename = file_name

object.attachment = data
```

Comment: I got everything working nicely by combining this answer with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6325039/574190).

Answer (score 1):

Convert your stringio.txt to file using this:

```
file = StringIO.new(obj)
file.original_filename = "#{self.username}.jpg"
```

and then assign your file to `profile_pic`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help since open() was already giving a StringIO object and there isn't a method named original_filename on StringIO. Though I found the issue and fixed it. It is :file_name instead of :filename

self.profile_pic.instance_write :file_name, "#{self.username}.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

My solution for creating files from a string:

```
class FileIO < StringIO
  def initialize(content:, filename:)
    super(content)
    @original_filename = filename
  end

  attr_reader :original_filename
end

FileIO.new(content: obj, filename: "#{username}.jpg")
```

This helped me solve the problem with the Carrierwave error when saving the file:

> *TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String*