# Add image from URL to Excel with Axlsx

Tags: ruby, carrierwave, axlsx

I'm using the ([Axlsx gem](https://github.com/randym/axlsx) and it's working great, but I need to add an image to a cell.
I know it can be done with an image file (see [Adding image to Excel file generated by Axlsx.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714193/adding-image-to-excel-file-generated-by-axlsx)), but I'm having a lot of trouble using our images stored in S3 (through Carrierwave).

Things I've tried:

```
# image.url = 'http://.../test.jpg'
ws.add_image(:image_src => image.url,:noSelect => true, :noMove => true) do |image|

# ArgumentError: File does not exist
```

or

```
ws.add_image(:image_src => image,:noSelect => true, :noMove => true) do |image|
# Invalid Data #<Object ...>
```

Not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `read` to pull the contents into a tempfile and use that location:

```
t = Tempfile.new('my_image')
t.binmode
t.write image.read
t.close
ws.add_image(:image_src => t.path, ...
```

Comment: `ArgumentError: File does not exist`. I think it's looking for that as though it's an absolute path when it's just the path in the URL.

Comment: Hmm, can you `read` it into a tempfile and use that location?  Updated to demonstrate...

Comment: Used something similar. `t.write open(image.url).read`, but BEWARE because this only works on images over 10kb (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496874/why-does-openuri-treat-files-under-10kb-in-size-as-stringio)

Answer (score 0):

To add an alternative answer for Paperclip & S3 as I couldn't find a reference for that besides this answer.

**I'm using Rails 5.0.2 and Paperclip 4.3.1.**

With image URLs like: `http://s3.amazonaws.com/prod/accounts/logos/000/000/001/original/logo.jpg?87879987987987`

```
@logo = @account.company_logo
if @logo.present?
  @logo_image = Tempfile.new(['', ".#{@logo.url.split('.').last.split('?').first}"])
  @logo_image.binmode # note that our tempfile must be in binary mode
  @logo_image.write open(@logo.url).read
  @logo_image.rewind
end
```

**In the .xlsx file**

```
sheet.add_image(image_src:  @logo_image.path, noSelect: true, noMove: true, hyperlink: "#") do |image|...
```

Reference link: http://mensfeld.pl/tag/tempfile/ for more reading.

The `.split('.').last.split('?').first` is to get .jpg from logo.jpg? 87879987987987.

Comment: You can simplify the `.split` ugliness with `File.extname(URI(@logo.url).path)`