# Sinatra, Twitter, and StringIO

Tags: twitter, sinatra, stringio

The `Twitter API` allows you to add media to your tweet via their `update_with_tweet` method.

I am using `Sinatra` and have my `Twitter` configurations all set up. I am able to succesfully post tweets with my app.

My app reads a webpage, extracts the photos from that page, and then is supposed to individually post them to Twitter. I am successfully extracting the photos from the page using `Nokogiri`.

But, I am having trouble converting those photos into a media type that `Twitter` will allow. Because I am also using the `uri` gem, given this example: `photo_url = "placekitten.com/300/300"`, I am able to call `media = open(photo_url)` and this returns a `StringIO`.

But, when I try posting that newly stored media with my post to `Twitter` I am given the error that `The IO object for media must respond to to_io (Twitter::Error::UnacceptableIO)`.

I am trying to figure out how to correctly format/call the image so that I can successfully post it to Twitter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced with same issue but using Rails.

Problem is in size of image: if size of image is less than 10kb then `open(photo_url)` will give you `StringIO` object, if size is more then 10kb then - `File` object which is saved in `tmp/` folder. `File` object respond's to `to_io` method and `StringIO` object doesn't.

What you can do - create file in `tmp` folder from your file, and then use this this file for posting to TW.
For example:

```
  img = open(url)
  if img.is_a?(StringIO)
    ext = File.extname(url)
    name = File.basename(url, ext)
    Tempfile.new([name, ext])
  else
    img
  end
```

Comment: This is indeed the problem. A different solution is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496874/why-does-openuri-treat-files-under-10kb-in-size-as-stringio

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the above problem is to force a `File` to be created.
And don't allow downloaded files to be created as `StringIO`.

Just include the following code into the top of the file with `:update_with_media` call.

```
require 'open-uri'

OpenURI::Buffer.send :remove_const, 'StringMax' if OpenURI::Buffer.const_defined?('StringMax')
OpenURI::Buffer.const_set 'StringMax', 0
```